Had had/had - Which to use in the given scenario?

Days before he was promoted, he'd written an article that I had to completely rewrite.

Days before he was promoted, he'd written an article that I'd had to completely rewrite.


Are both these sentences grammatically correct? Is it necessary to use had had here? Or is the sentence fine with just one had? Does using had had instead of just had affect the meaning of the sentence in any way?

KISS! There's only one possible meaning anyway, so: Days before he was promoted, he wrote an article that I had to completely rewrite.

The past perfect "had had" is only necessary in cases where you want to clarify that an action or state occurred even further back in time than another past action. For example, in "by the time he was promoted he had had three articles published", it helps to indicate that the three articles had all been published before the time of the promotion rather than at that time, which "he had three articles published" could mean.
There is no need in your example because the two past actions are already clearly two different points in time. "He'd written" is the past perfect, and "I had to completely rewrite" is in the simple past tense.
